# JPEG DCT tranformation issue

Tags: python-3.x, jpeg, dct

I've tried to program JPEG transformations in python,
I've been able to do all the stept up until now, where I need to convert my data back into a new image.
this is my code for now, beware, my usage of variables is very poor. I didn't have a lot of time to code this and I'm still learning how to code in python.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import skimage.util
from scipy import fftpack

#
#ALLEMAAL INFORMATIE GEEN BEREKENINGEN
img = Image.open('C:\\Users\\dbe\\Documents\\KULAK\\2018-2019\\Semester 1\\Python\\Python FFt\\mario4.png')  
img = img.convert('L') # converteren naar monochrome
img.show()
pixels = list(img.getdata())
pixelArray = np.array(img.getdata())
grootte = list(img.size)
kolommen, rijen = img.size

#tot hier allemaal informatie

  #PixelMatrix
pixelMatrix = []
while pixels != []:
    pixelMatrix.append(pixels[:kolommen])
    pixels = pixels[kolommen:]

pixelMatrix = np.array(pixelMatrix)


# 8 op 8 
foto_dct = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(pixelMatrix, block_shape=(8, 8))
print("Voor aftrekking:","\n",foto_dct[3,3])




    # (1) -128
for x in foto_dct:
    x = x - 128 # pixel 8 op 8 matrix -128
print("Voor DCT","\n",foto_dct[3,3])

    # (2) DCT 2x
for x in foto_dct:
    x = fftpack.dct(fftpack.dct(x.T,norm = 'ortho').T,norm ='ortho') # 2x dct
print("Voor de deling",'\n',foto_dct[3,3])

    # (3) quantisatie ( /Q)

Q = np.array([[16,11,10,16,24,40,51,61],[12,12,14,19,26,58,60,55],[14,13,16,24,40,57,69,56],[14,17,22,29,51,87,80,62],[18,22,37,56,68,109,103,77],[24,35,55,64,81,104,113,92],[49,64,78,87,103,121,120,101],[72,92,95,98,112,100,103,99]]) # quantisatie matrix

for x in foto_dct:
        x = np.divide(x,Q)
print("Na de deling:","\n",foto_dct[3,3])

    # (4) *Q
for x in foto_dct:
    x = np.multiply(x,Q)
print("Na vermenigvuldiging terug:","\n",foto_dct[3,3])

    # (5) idct 2x 
for x in foto_dct:
        x = fftpack.idct(fftpack.idct(x.T,norm = 'ortho').T,norm ='ortho')
print("Na IDCT:","\n",foto_dct[3,3])

    # (6) +128
for x in foto_dct:
        x = (x + 128 ).clip(0,255) 
print("Na optelling","\n",foto_dct[3,3])
print("test","\n",foto_dct[3,4])


foto_dct = np.reshape(foto_dct,(kolommen,rijen)) 

flatArray = np.array(foto_dct.flatten())

finalim = Image.new('L',(rijen,kolommen))
finalim.putdata(flatArray)
finalim.show()
```

Or here is a link to a screenshot: 
[Screenshot of my code](https://gyazo.com/bab23cda220657a7b42948e60f6b1a8d)
Now the problem is that when I convert the 8x8 matrices back into a 128x128 ( rijen x kolommen) matrix, the order gets messed up and my original picture:
[Original picture](https://gyazo.com/9c5f7802ca13da3a24d7d5a77a2bf338)
now looks like this:
[JPEG picture](https://gyazo.com/1dd3d495c6b526da0becddb6d7ddd57b)
Can anyone help me out on why this isn't correct?

Extra information : foto_dct.shape is (16,16,8,8)
                  : when I take an 8x8 pixelmatrix before # (1), and when I take the corresponding  8x8 pixelmatrix after the operations, after # (6) they are correct when I print them.

foto_dct[5,7] : [BEFORE TRANSFORMATION](https://gyazo.com/794ac4cb0fc5bbc50e9fd8b31cd227fe)

foto_dct[5,7] : [AFTER  TRANSFORMATION](https://gyazo.com/bb26acc1f77dfddf036e61a7a985ddc6)
Though I can't manage to combine the newly made matrices back into an image.
Kind regards.

Comment: @NilsWerner this is my new question.

Comment: I am confused by this question.